# Explain about the ActiveMQ parameter required in JavaScript code with Example

Tags: javascript, java, activemq-classic

Please explain to me the ActiveMQ parameters required(uri,myDestination,myId) in JavaScript code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var amq = org.activemq.Amq;
  amq.init({ 
    uri: 'amq', 
    logging: true,
    timeout: 20
  });
</script>
amq.sendMessage(myDestination,myMessage);
var myHandler =
{
  rcvMessage: function(message)
  {
    alert("received "+message);
  }
};

amq.addListener(myId, myDestination, myHandler.rcvMessage);
```

I have written al the JMS code and created my API
http://localhost:8080/nbt-messenger/chat-service/RecieveMessage?queueId=Case_4&sentTo=Mark
Whenever I hit this API, I am getting the response, but my problem is like polling this api again and again won't give me the smooth experience as it may hang the browser, so wanted to use above javascript listener, but I don't know what does those parameters mean...

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html. You can use this documentation.

Comment: from here only I picked this code, I need to understand these parameters, I am not getting it there, can you give the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html):

> ...myId is a string identifier that can be used for a later call to amq.removeHandler(myId) and myDestination is a URL string address of the destination (e.g. topic://MY.NAME or channel://MY.NAME). When a message is received, a call back to the myHandler.rcvMessage function passes the message to your handling code.

In other words:

- **myId**: a string identifier that can be used for a later call to `amq.removeHandler(myId)`
- **myDestination**: a URL string address of the destination (e.g. `topic://MY.NAME` or `channel://MY.NAME`)
- **myHandler.rcvMessage**: a call back function which will be used to pass the message to your handling code

For what it's worth, I would recommend against using the ActiveMQ REST interface because it's specific to ActiveMQ and therefore will not work with any other broker. Instead, I recommend you use a standard protocol like STOMP or AMQP which have Javascript clients readily available and better support/documentation.

Comment: thanx for your suggestion, but I integrated it with Java JMS, so I found the better way to do it and also made some changes in its JavaScript library and then it worked fine for me... We have to use this ActiveMQ js, reason being is, they have handled all the polling problems, otherwise your personalised polling can slow down to your performance....